# Module cannot be initialized zf3 already searched internet

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I'm receiving the following error in a **Zend Framework 3 Application**:

Fatal error: Uncaught Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException: Module (Serve) could not be initialized.

**I'm aware that there is some answers however none seem to point to zf3 and ive already scanned them without answer. I cannot seem to find an answer through research.**

Is it possible that my application is not loading modules? I have modified the application config just a tad so it might just not be loading the module itself.

I have a folder structure:

```
- module
   -Serve
      -src
         -Module.php
         -Controller
            -IndexController.php
      -config
         -module.config.php
      -view
```

I have the module added to the modules array inside `/config/application.config.php`.

Here is my `module.config.php`

```
namespace Serve;

return array(
        'controllers' => array(
                'invokables' => array(
                        'Serve\Controller\Index' => 'Serve\Controller\IndexController',
                ),
        ),

        // The following section is new and should be added to your file
        'router' => array(
                'routes' => array(
                        'serve' => array(
                                'type'    => 'segment',
                                'options' => array(
                                        'route'    => '/srv[/:action]',
                                        'constraints' => array(
                                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                                        ),
                                        'defaults' => array(
                                                'controller' => 'Serve\Controller\Index',
                                                'action'     => 'index',
                                        ),
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
        ),

        'view_manager' => array(
                'template_path_stack' => array(
                        'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
                ),
                'strategies' => array(
                        'ViewJsonStrategy',
                ),
        ),
);
```

Here is my `Serve\Module.php` file:

```
<?php
namespace Serve;

class Module
{  
    public function getConfig()
    {       
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }
 }
```

I have a bunch of business logic inside my `Application\Module.php` however nothing that looks to disrupt loading modules.

I cannot seem to find an answer through research. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you add the module to the autoloader? https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/composer.json#L23

In ZF2, we used to autoload pretty much anything through the Module class, now we can just do it in composer, which is easier and allow options such as --optimize (generate classmaps) and --classmap-authoritative (do not load any class outside of the classmap).

Don't forget to composer dumpautoload after editing the composer.json file :)